# capturing using sed

Tags: sed

I have a file like this

```
x   +   chrX    15362   15364   +   100(3)  *(0)    *(0)    *(0)    100(5)  *(0)    100(1)
y   +   chrX    153626  153626  +   100(80) 98.56(79)   100(40) 100(47) 100(88) 4(23)
```

I want to capture the values within parenthesis and just print them so that the output looks like this

```
x   +   chrX    15362   15364   +   3   0   0   0   5   0   1
y   +   chrX    153626  153626  +   80  79  40  47  88  23
```

I want to do this in sed.

I tried something like this but it is not working

```
sed -r 's/^.*\((\d+)\)/\1/g'
```

Also how can I get rid of everything within the parenthesis including the parenthesis so that I get the following output also

```
x   +   chrX    15362   15364   +   100 *   *   *   100 *   100
y   +   chrX    153626  153626  +   100 98.56   100 100 100 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/([^)]*)//g' file
x   +   chrX    15362   15364   +   100  *    *    *    100  *    100
y   +   chrX    153626  153626  +   100 98.56   100 100 100 4
```

Here, we use `sed` to remove any parenthesis in the input.  The expression `([^)]*)` matches a left parenthesis followed by any number of non-right parenthesis characters (i.e. the number), followed by a right parenthesis. You could also use `([0-9]*)` here.

```
$ sed 's/[^[:blank:]]*(\([^)]*\))/\1/g' file
x   +   chrX    15362   15364   +   3  0    0    0    5  0    1
y   +   chrX    153626  153626  +   80 79   40 47 88 23
```

Here, we delete the bit before the parenthesis, and the parentheses themselves, and replace all of that with the thing that was inside the parenthesis.  The stuff before the `(` is matched by `[^[:blank:]]*`, i.e. any number of non-blank characters, followed by the same expression as in the first `sed` command, but capturing the contents between `(` and `)`.  The captured string is referenced in the replacement part of the command by `\1`.

---

Your command,

```
sed -r 's/^.*\((\d+)\)/\1/g'
```

does not work properly because `\d` is a PCRE (a Perl-like regular expression).  Replacing `\d` with `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` would not make it work better as it would replace the whole line with the number inside the last parenthesis.

Comment: For the first part of your answer what is `[^` doing?

Comment: @user3138373 `[^)]` matches one character that is _not_ `)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `sed -r 's/[^[:blank:]]*\(([[:digit:]]+)\)/\1/g'`

- finds zero or more non-whitespace chars followed by open paren followed by digits (capture) followed by close paren
- replace with just the captured digits
- do that globally in the line
- `\d` is a PCRE construct, not from extended regex

Pipe the output into `| column -t` for prettiness.